# Make quote begin at text, not at tag

Tags: css, alignment, quote

I'm having some trouble getting my quote standing next to my text.
At the moment, the quotation mark is standing on the very left side.

Without centering the text, it works fine, but when I center the text, things get messy.

```
.center
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BpTdL/2/

How can I make sure that quote is next to my text, not the  tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `blockquote:before` block of CSS to be

```
blockquote:before {
    content: "\201C";
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #7a7a7a;
    display: inline;
    line-height: .22;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You'll need to adjust the padding-top of the blockquote a little because it gets cut off

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mutzp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change this:

```
blockquote:before {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  }
```

for this:

```
blockquote:before {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;           /* Line changed */
  top: -20px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  }
```

Is this what you wanted? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BpTdL/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and put the quote and text in divs and use this code to move them around

```
position:relative;
left:100px;
```

This will allow you to move to a postion that you want